# Pandas DataFrame - Access Values That are created on the fly

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I am trying figure out something which I can easily preform on excel but I am having a hard time to understand how to do it on a Pandas Data Frame without using loops.

Suppose that I have a data frame as follows:

```
+------------+-------+-------+-----+------+
|    Date    | Price | Proxy | Div | Days |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+------+
| 13/01/2021 | 10    |    20 | 0.5 | NaN  |
| 08/01/2021 | NaN   |    30 | 0.6 | 5    |
| 04/01/2021 | NaN   |    40 | 0.7 | 4    |
| 03/01/2021 | NaN   |    50 | 0.8 | 1    |
| 01/01/2021 | NaN   |    60 | 0.9 | 2    |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+------+
```

The task is to fill all the Price where price is null. In excel I would suppose that `Date` is column `A` and first row of `Date` id row 2 then to fill NaN in row 2 of `Price` I would use the formula `=(B2)/(((C3/C2)*D3)*E3)=2.22`.

Now I want to use the value `2.22` on the fly to fill NaN in row 3 of `Price` reason being to fill nan of row 3 I need to make use of filled row 2 value. Hence the formula in excel would to fill row 3 price would be `=(B3)/(((C4/C3)*D4)*E4)`.

1 way would be to loop over all the rows of Data Frame that I don't want to do. What would be the vectorised approach to solve this problem?

**Expected Output**

```
+------------+-------+-------+-----+------+
|    Date    | Price | Proxy | Div | Days |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+------+
| 13/01/2021 |    10 |    20 | 0.5 | NA   |
| 08/01/2021 |  2.22 |    30 | 0.6 | 5    |
| 04/01/2021 |  0.60 |    40 | 0.7 | 4    |
| 03/01/2021 |  0.60 |    50 | 0.8 | 1    |
| 01/01/2021 |  0.28 |    60 | 0.9 | 2    |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+------+
```

`Current_Price = Prev Price (non-nan) / (((Current_Proxy/Prev_Proxy) * Div) * Days)`

**Edit**

Create initial data frame using code below

```
data = {'Date': ['2021-01-13', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-01'],
        'Price':[10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan],
        'Proxy':[20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        'Div':[0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
        'Days':[np.nan, 5, 4, 1, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is actually a cumulated product:

```
df['Price'] = (df['Price'].combine_first(df['Proxy'].shift()/df.eval('Proxy*Div*Days'))
               .cumprod().round(2))
```

Output:

```
         Date  Price  Proxy  Div  Days
0  2021-01-13  10.00     20  0.5   NaN
1  2021-01-08   2.22     30  0.6   5.0
2  2021-01-04   0.60     40  0.7   4.0
3  2021-01-03   0.60     50  0.8   1.0
4  2021-01-01   0.28     60  0.9   2.0
```

Comment: can you explain a bit on what was your thought process I am having hard time thinking in the right path. Any way to enhance my skills on Pandas Data Frame?

Comment: I just broke down the operation. For row 1 -> 10*20/(30*0.6*5), row 2, same thing from the previous value, so it could actually be calculated sequentially from row 1 that itself depends on row 0: this is a cumulated product. So, in the the end, only calculate the factor from one row to the next and finally apply this with 10 as a starting point. Not sure if this helps? You can comment the successive lines in the pipeline to see the intermediates in the calculation

Comment: Thanks it was helpful.